# Problem with process builder and new records

Tags: flow, process-builder

I have a process that I created in the Process Builder which...

- Runs whever an Opportunity is created or edited
- Includes logic requiring Opportunity have Amount > 0 and Stage be "Closed Won"
- Posts the Opportunity ID to the chatter feed (for debugging)
- Calls a flow that requires the Opportunity ID

I'm expecting (hoping) that when both conditions are met the ID shows on chatter and the flow is called.

Unfortunately, when a record is created and both conditions are met the flow is not receiving the Opportunity ID desipite the ID showing in the chatter feed.

However, if I do the following as separate steps...

1. Create an Opportunity with Amount > 0 but Stage as anything but "Closed Won" (save)
2. Edit the Opportunity and change the Stage to "Closed Won"

The flow is called and is receiving the Opportunity ID.

Any idea what's going wrong with new records?

Comment: What is the logic in your first 'decision' on the PB.  What is it set to?

Comment: The logic is Opportunity.Amount > 0 and Opportunity.Stage = "Closed Won".   However, I seriously doubt its a logic issue since the actions are Post to ID Chatter and Run the Flow.  Post to Chatter is working so the actions are being called.  It's a matter of the flow running correctly only on updates but not record creates.

Comment: What is the Flow doing?  Is there any sort of validation rule or something that might be running into a problem for you?  It sounds like the PB is working fine... so that means something is funky within the Flow?  Assuming the Opportunity.Id is always passed in - since the record is created and it would be working the same for all scenarios to pass in the Flow.